# Templated member function call g++ error : no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates, template-matching

g++ encounter an error on that sample.

I have a class `Option` who contain an `std::string`

`OptionValue` inherited from `Option` with an template type and a templated argument of type `std::string` for the key.

`OptionManager` manage `OptionValue` in a `std::map<std::string, Option*>`
`OptionManager` have a member function `create` :

```
  template <typename T, std::string & key>
  void  create(const T & value);
```

g++ don't complain if I don't invoke :

```
  OptionManager *manager = new OptionManager;
  manager->create<int, "my_key">(3);
```

g++ don't like `create` call, here is the error :
`no matching function for call to OptionManager::create(int)`

If somebody can help me by showing me the way, I thank him very much !!! :)

Here is the code :

**Option.hpp**

```
class                                   Option
{
public:
  Option(std::string & key) :
  key_(key)
  {}

  virtual ~Option()
  {}

 protected:
   std::string                           key_;
 };
```

**OptionValue.hpp**

```
template                                <typename T, std::string & key>
class                                   OptionValue : public Option
{
public:
  OptionValue<T, key>(T val) :
  Option(key),
  val_(val)
  {}

  virtual ~OptionValue()
  {}

private:
  T                                     val_;
};
```

**OptionManager.hpp**

```
class                                   OptionManager
{
public:
  OptionManager(){}
  ~OptionManager(){}
  template                              <typename T, std::string & key>
  void                                  create(const T & value)
  {
    Option                              *tmp;

    tmp = new OptionValue<T, key>(value);
    this->list_.insert(t_pair(key, tmp));
  }
private:
  std::map<std::string, Option*>                        list_;
  typedef std::map<std::string, Option*>::iterator      t_iter;
  typedef std::pair<std::string, Option*>               t_pair;
```

};

**main.cpp**

```
int                             main()
{
  OptionManager                 *manager;

  manager = new OptionManager;
  manager->create<int, "my_key">(3);
  return 0;
}
```

**g++ error**

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘OptionManager::create(int)’
main.cpp:8:35: note: candidate is:
OptionManager.hpp:14:12: note: template<class T, std::string& key> void OptionManager::create(const T&)
```

Comment: That's the most original code formatting I've seen for ages. It's horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second template parameter is of type `std::string &`. You cannot initialise this with a temporary object (as, in your case, the one created by converting a string literal to `std::string`).

Comment: Tanks ! You help me a lot !